# How to pass an argument with a leading slash to npm script

Tags: npm, webpack, git-bash, npm-scripts

I have a package.json with some scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack-cli --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack-cli --mode development",
 }
```

I just want to pass an additional parameter from the command line and not from the scripts in the `package.json`, so I run a basic command line like this:

```
npm run build:dev -- --test /toto/
```

I would like this command:

> webpack-cli --mode development "--test" "/toto/"

But, it runs this command:

> webpack-cli --mode development "--test" "C:/Program Files/Git/toto/"

Do you have any idea how could I avoid to have the absolute path in front the string "/toto" ?

Comment: Is the `/toto/` argument for a pathname to a directory in your project directory? Are you using using Git Bash?

Comment: Yes I am using git bash. I found the workaround below

Comment: Yes, I suspected it was Git Bash related, I was only able to reproduce the same behavior using that. There is the [`MSYS_NO_PATHCONV`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1462) environment variable that can be temporarily set to `1` to prevent this conversion, however unfortunately it doesn't work with npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compose the command with `"'/toto/'"`

```
npm run build:dev -- --test "'/toto/'"
```